# How do I determine which application handles a global shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I have some global shortcut that does nothing apparent, but is overriding the combination in all applications. The shortcut is <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, which overrides the "Google Search" in Safari, and the Replace in Sublime Text 2.

Is there any way to determine which application this shortcut is actually being handled by, or what action it is triggering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've re-installed the OS many times since, so the original issue no longer bugs me. But I did find a third party application "Shortcut Detective" (http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) that comes very close.

Comment: Fantastic! Despite Googling for ages... must have missed this. This solved my problem of Cmd(⌘)-Opt(⌥)-F not working in Chrome. Turns out Divvy was the culprit. Well worth the bounty -- ty:)

Comment: Too bad the app hasn't been updated in years.  It crashes whenever the system handles a shortcut, for example.

Comment: At least, before crashing, it serves its purpose! Finally found the "violator" and can report the bug to its developers. Thanks @answered for this! Makes my day.

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully answer your question.

Go to System Preferences using Spotlight or the Apple Menu(). Then click on Keyboard.

[image]

When in the Keyboard Pane of System Preferences click on "Shortcuts"(on the upper part of the window), then click on App Shortcuts. There you will find listed all the third-party apps that have keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. Apps that steal global shortcuts unfortunately don't show up there.

Comment: @MattTagg There is no way it can not show up there unless you are leaving an application open(maybe you didn't notice) that is using those shortcuts.

Comment: That's not correct. *System Preferences -> App Shortcuts* is specifically for *user defined* shortcuts. It does not list global application shortcuts

Comment: @MattTagg I did not add any shortcuts there, those have already been there and I have never added a shortcut there. Those are all the global shortcuts.

Comment: I believe you. However, your conclusions are wrong because they're based on faulty inferences. In your image above, *Google Chrome* does not put *"Shift-F5"* there by default. So maybe you should be looking for malware or asking the babysitter why it's there ;)