# Which application/command catches a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard

Is there a way to find out which application or command catches a global hotkey in osx?

Comment: I doubt you can catch this, as the application which consumes the key listens to that specific command and does not log back to OSX it has used it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine which application handles a global shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64086/how-do-i-determine-which-application-handles-a-global-shortcut)